# Vue Native: attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: react-native, vue.js, vuex, asyncstorage

For those who don't know - Vue Native is a wrapper for React Native. You write React Native apps using the VueJS framework.

The problem:
I'm trying to store an api list using AsyncStorage, but I'm getting an error **"attempted to assign to readonly property"**.

The api list looks like this:

```
apiList: [
    {name: "api1", url: "https://example_url1"}, 
    {name: "api2", url: "https://example_url2"},
]
```

The user can add an API to the list. This is done using a VueX action.
If the api is not on the list it's added (push).

```
[ADD_API](context, { name, url }) {
    let api = context.getters.getApiFromList(name);

    if (name && url && !api) {
        context.commit(APPEND_API_LIST, { name, url });

        // AsyncStorage.removeItem('apiList', () => {
        //     AsyncStorage.setItem('apiList', context.state.apiList)
        // });
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('APIs').then(() => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('APIs', context.state.apiList);
        });
    }
},
```

The error occurs when I add the AsyncStorage fragment. I'm pretty new to React Native, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Since it's readonly, my first though is the solution is not to force a store on this, since it's readonly, but it's your algoritme/pattern that's my need to be change?

Comment: But why is it readonly? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I have never tried this before. I could just tell that you were going about it in a wrong way. The problem can never be if something is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a lack of oversight on my part. The [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/) state:

```
static setItem(key: string, value: string, [callback]: ?(error: ?Error) => void)
```

Simply put - only strings can be stored using AsyncStorage.
This problem has been addressed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272533/asyncstorage-react-native-save-an-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596187/react-native-asyncstorage-storing-values-other-than-strings).

The solution is simple:

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem('APIs').then(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('APIs', JSON.stringify(context.state.apiList));
});
```